# Splitting data and then performing rbind()

Tags: r, matrix

I am working on a very big dataset, and here I created a sparse matrix, but unfortunately, my R memory is full. So I decided to subset the data and then do the rbind(), but I am getting the following error

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Images are neither code nor data unless the topic is image processing. You should click the "r" at the bottom of your question, go to the "Info" tab and then do some reading to get pointers on how to pose a good question.

Answer (score 0):

The image shows you used `cbind()` not `rbind()`.

[image]

If you wanted to use `rbind()`, fix the typo and rerun the operation.

Comment: I am sorry, I have highlighted cbind() error instead of rbind() error (above error to which I have highlighted). Since I was getting an error with rbid(), I tried to use cbind(). But in either of the case, the error was the same.My problem here is, though I split the data and run the code, R is allocating memory to both the splits seperately, but when i try to rbind() them, I am facing this errror.

Comment: What happens when you use `nrow()` and `ncol()` on each data frame you want to bind? Do the numbers of rows (for `cbind()`) and/or columns (for `rbind()`) match?